# My attempt to compare string equality in CMake with if(... EQUAL ...) is not working. Why?

Tags: if-statement, cmake

I am working on a project using CMake.
I want to do stuff based on the value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.

It seems that the CMake if statement does not work as I expected.

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = >${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}<")

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} EQUAL "Windows")
    message(STATUS  "Why am I not called?")
else()
    message(STATUS "I should not be here!\nCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = >${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}<.")
endif()

# Output:
# > [CMake] -- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = >Windows<
# > [CMake] -- I should not be here!
# > [CMake] CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = >Windows<.
```

The message before the if shows that `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` is set to "Windows" but still the script lands on the else.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To compare strings use STREQUAL. EQUAL is for numbers.
2. STREQUAL expands both sides as variables. Do not `${...}`.

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
```

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#variable-expansion .

> Why am I not called?

`EQUAL` just returns false if there are invalid numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[`EQUAL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#equal) is for comparing equality of numeric strings: "*True if the given string or variable's value is a valid number and equal to that on the right.*". Use [`STREQUAL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#strequal) to compare equality of strings (including non-numeric-"valued" strings).

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
```

Unlike what KamilKuk said, technically, wrapping `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` in `${}` is fine. `if()` is a command, so see the docs for [command arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-arguments). I'd recommend against using `${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}`, since it will be processed as an [unquoted argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#unquoted-argument), and if you've declared any variables with the name `Linux` or `Windows`, or any other system name, then that variable will then be referenced inside of the `if()` command as the value to use for comparison, which you almost certainly don't want (you'd face the same possible footgun if you don't quote the right-hand argument, ex. `Windows` instead of `"Windows"`). If you pass it as a quoted argument, that's not a problem:

```
if ("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" STREQUAL "Windows")
```

I like to play it safe and just quote pretty much everything when I'm passing command arguments for `if()` comparison operands.